# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile' even when changed tf.gfile.* to tf.io.gfile.* in line 131

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

```
!python {'/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {'/content/Training'} -l {'/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {'/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{'/content/Testing'} -l {'/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

running which gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/generate_tfrecord.py", line 61, in <module>
    label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(args.labels_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 132, in load_labelmap
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/generate_tfrecord.py", line 61, in <module>
    label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(args.labels_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 132, in load_labelmap
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'
```

I have followed a recommended me to change tf.gfile.* to tf.io.gfile.* in line 111, executing which I'm getting the above error.

MacOS Catalina 10.15.3. Google Collab (Online)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since in Tensorflow 2 Gfile is moved under [tf.io.gfile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile) you can go to `label_map_util.py` file and replace the name from `tf.gfile.GFile` to `tf.io.gfile.GFile`.
If you have already tried that option then you can downgrade the version of `Tensorflow` to `1.x` in `colab` using below magic command before importing `Tensorflow`.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
```